# Compile C# project with Emacs

Tags: c#, emacs

I use emacs to code and compile C# project.

My project folder contain:

```
--\test
----Helloworld.cs
----make.bat
```

Then I open Helloworld.cs in a buffer and M-x compile, emacs will compile project for me.

But if my project folder construction is like this:

```
--\test
----\src
------Helloworld.cs
----make.bat
```

Then I open Helloworld.cs in a buffer and M-x compile, emacs cannot find make.bat.

I have to locate make.bat for "compile command" in minibuffer.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I used vs2010 at home. But sometime I have to use emacs in USB on other computers. And CEDET is heavyweight. Some cs files and a make.bat is fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `../make.bat` works, then indeed it's a good option.  If not, you can use `cd ../; ./make.bat` as your compilation command instead.  You could even make Emacs look up the directory hierarchy for a `make.bat` file and add as many `../` as needed.

Comment: Thanks. "../make.bat" does not work. But "cd ../ & make" as compilation command worked.

Answer (score 1):

emacs compile generally runs from the same directory that the source exists in. Set your M-x compile command to `../make.bat` (or give it an absolute path) and everything should work.